# problem with beautiful soup and td element extraction

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, data-mining

*Another beautifulsoup extraction question*

I'm sorry I know these questions get asked a lot but I'm lost and I'm not quite understanding some stuff.

First of all, this is my basic code to extract data from a site:

```
import requests
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

my_protein_list = ["ArthCp002"]
for protein in my_protein_list:
    text = requests.get('https://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?ath:' + protein).text
    soup = BS(text,'html.parser')
    AGI = soup.find("td", {"class":"td11"})
print(AGI)
```

I want to get the TAIR value from the website. My first question is, why does the above code only outputs the following

```
<td class="td11" style="border-color:#000; border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px; border-style: solid"><div style="width:555px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden">psbA<br/>
</div></td>
```

why doesn't it give everything within that td class?

Also the TAIR I need is found in  element number 3. So when I add the table element to my code, it returns none. For example, I add this code just before the print:

```
AGI = AGI.table
```

why didn't it scrape data from the table element? Can someone please help me understand? cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You're targeting the wrong element. TAIR is an anchor.

Here, try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?ath:arthcp002"
anchors = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser").find_all("a", href=True)

for anchor in anchors:
    if "Tair" in anchor["href"]:
        print(anchor["href"], anchor.getText())
```

Output:

```
http://arabidopsis.org/servlets/TairObject?type=locus&name=ATCG00020 ATCG00020
```